# What technology allows page content to change without changing the URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have seen this on some survey websites. What is the C# code they use on the client side to keep the URL same, but when clicking the "Next" button, the same **aspx** page is maintained

1. **without** having any query string;
2. without any change even a character in the url; and
3. the grid, the data , the content, the questions keep changing?

Can anyone give a code-wise example how to achieve this?

My main query is how is this done in code-behind to change data of page and maintain same url.

Comment: That's the [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) magic. There are many JQuery plugings for this, for example [this one](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination) with a [live demo](http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm). You can also program it easily using JQuery [Get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [Post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or any other wrapper that use XmlHttpRequest object.

Comment: @oleksii, you don't need ajax to return different content without changing the URL!

Comment: @SimonMcKenzie please describe how would you do pagination without AJAX?

Comment: @oleksii - you could maintain the page index in a session variable on the server and the user could page by POSTing form fields. Websites have been around for a lot longer than ajax!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"change data of page and maintain same url." Answer is [Server.Transfer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.transfer.aspx).
This method will preserve url.

Comment: But transfer to where? It is a possible addition to @Wiktor's answer though.

Comment: It only works once, though. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090698/why-does-consecutive-calls-to-server-transfer-change-the-url.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing simpler that a session, maintainted at the server side. Store a "current question number" in session, increment it at each succesfull postback and you have what you ask about.

Another possibility - a cookie which contains "current question number".

Both cookie and session are invisible in the query string of course.

Answer (score 1):

The **Next** button may submit a form using the HTTP POST method.  The form data may contain the session, question and response data.  The site uses that to build a new response.  Unlike a GET, a POST does not incorporate data into the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Developers will typically accomplish this task by using AJAX. The basic premise behind it is that **only a certain portion of the page** (e.g. a grid or content area) will make a server call and retrieve the results (using Javascript). The effect achieved is that there has not been a full post back, which is why you don't see the URL or parameters changing.

It is possible to do this using jQuery, pure Javascript, or Microsoft's [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx).

oleksii's comment has some good links as well:

> That's the [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) magic. There are many JQuery plugings for this, for
>   example [this one](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/pagination) with a [live demo](http://d-scribe.de/webtools/jquery-pagination/demo/demo_options.htm). You can also program it easily
>   using JQuery [Get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) or [Post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) or any other wrapper that use XmlHttpRequest
>   object.