# Why does consecutive calls to Server.Transfer change the url?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using `Server.Transfer` to load the contents of another page when clicking a button. This works as expected and the url stays the same. However, if I try to load a third page at the click of a button in the second page, the url changes to that of the second page. I would expect it to keep the url of the first page.

Example:

1. `Page1.aspx` loads.

   - Url: `.../Page1.aspx`
   - Content: `Page1.aspx`
2. `Server.Transfer("~/Page2.aspx")` on button click.

   - Url: `.../Page1.aspx`
   - Content: `Page2.aspx`
3. `Server.Transfer("~/Page3.aspx")` on button click

   - Url: `.../Page2.aspx`
   - Content: `Page3.aspx`

Why does the url change in the third step?

Comment: Do you mean the URL that is returned or the one in the user's address bar? Server.Transfer does not change the URL on the client side.

Comment: on step 2 you should check the Action attribute of your form. I'd bet it's page2.aspx (which would make sense)

Comment: @JohnFx I mean the url in the address bar. It does change, which is what I thought was weird. The answer from Tom Haigh (and jbl's comment) explains why this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `Server.Transfer()` the execution of the 1st page is stopped and the 2nd page is executed instead within the same HTTP request. The 2nd page (Page2.aspx) is then executed in the same way that it would be for a any normal request made directly to its URL, so the action of the form is set to its own URL (despite being called from `Server.Transfer()`).

If this was not the case then when the form is submitted it would post to Page1.aspx (as you  are expecting), but this page would not necessarily contain the same controls and be able to process the request.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. So is there a way to keep the url?

Comment: I suppose you could use user controls instead of pages and manage which one is hidden/shown etc. from one single page (and maybe a multiview). This is probably going to end up being a mess though, with large viewstate and sub-pages that you can't actually access directly from a URL (i.e. you have to click through a few postbacks to get anywhere). you could also consider using an iframe to mask URL changes, but again this isn't great.

Answer (score -3):

This one may help:

```
Response.Redirect("~/page.aspx",false)
```

Comment: That's not at all what the OP was asking about.